# Where can i find haskell function implementations

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

does anyone know, where i can find the implementations of haskell functions ?

I tried searching it in google, but had no success.

Grz

Comment: can someone please tell me, why i got an -1 rating, just because i asked a question ?

Comment: It's quite lame that people downvote without explaining why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here it is main sites:

[Hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/)

[Hayoo!](http://holumbus.fh-wedel.de/hayoo/hayoo.html)

[Platform modules](http://lambda.haskell.org/platform/doc/current/frames.html)

[Hackage](http://hackage.haskell.org/)

You could click at the "Source" to look at the source

Answer (score 0):

Click the "Source" links on the Hackage documentation for your library of choice; or just "cabal unpack" the library and have a look inside with your editor of choice.